# I am trying to create a number of Employee objects same as the number of line it reads from the file

Tags: java, bluej

list of lines
private ArrayList lines;

```
list of Employee objects
private ArrayList<Employee> employeeList;

the file information of employee
private FileReader file;

public HumanResource(String fileName)
{
    file = new FileReader(fileName);
    ArrayList<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int k = 0; k < file.getLines().size(); k++)
    {
       employeeList.add(new Employee (file.getLines().get(k)));
       
    }
}
```

This is what I came up with so far but idk if this is right?

Comment: Please explain exactly what isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way of doing it is using a [BufferReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and with it you can read each line.

```
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))){
  
  string st;
  ArrayList<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
  while ((st = br.readLine()) != null)
    employeeList.add(new Employee(st));
  }
}
```

Notice that I am using try{} to warp the bufferedReader in order for it to auto close

Comment: But does my code work? Because I have no idea how to check it

Comment: @harisfaizal _I have no idea how to check it_ Just run your code and see if it produces your desired output.

Comment: @harisfaizal, run it and see. It seems like it should work.